# Delete element from array based on member properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

say my object looks like the following

```
var jsonObj = [{
    "id":1,
    "name":"john"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"john2"
  }
]
```

I would like to delete members of the array where `jsonObj.id` is equal to 1

How do I do it?

Comment: delete jsonObj.id = 1

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as

```
var newObj = jsonObj.filter(function(item) { 
   return item.id !== 1;  
});
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 3):

try like this.

```
 jsonObj.forEach(function(item,i){
   if(item.id == 1)
    jsonObj.splice(i,1);
})
```

Comment: Why introduce angular?

Comment: because the question is "ANGULAR js json object deleting".

Comment: Good point. Still, the question has nothing to do with angular.

Comment: Angular has been removed from the question now

Comment: @SkinnyJ - I am actually working on angular, so its just I thought there could be some specific function to do it so.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can also use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) **filter** or **reject**:

**_.filter**

`jsonObj = _.filter(jsonObj, function(obj){ return obj.id != 1; });`

result = > `[{"id":2,"name":"john2"}]`

**_.reject**

`jsonObj = _.reject(jsonObj, function(obj){ return obj.id == 1; });`

result => `[{"id":2,"name":"john2"}]`